# splitting multiple strings in one column, to one column per string type

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataframe like:

```
|column1   |
|a,b,c     |
|d,b       |
|a & b,c   |
```

and i'd like to have it like this

```
column_a | column_b | column_c | column_d | column_a & b
1        | 1        | 1        |0         | 0         
0        | 1        | 0        |1         | 0
1        | 1        | 1        |0         | 1
```

similar to get dummies, except that I have multiple strings per cell

i don't believe there are repeat strings in a cell, so no '2's

any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Any code you have tried for this?

Comment: to be completely honest, i'm at a loss for how to start

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something like this:

```
data = '''|column1   |
|a,b,c     |
|d,b       |
|a & b,c   |'''

rows = [r.strip() for r in data.replace('\n','').split('|')[3:] if r.strip() != '']

values = []
for r in rows:
    values += r.split(',')
values = set(values)

print(' | '.join(['column_' + v for v in values]))
for r in rows:
    output = ''
    for v in values:
        if v in r:
            output += '1'
        else:
            output += '0'
        output += '        | '
    print(output)
```

You'll have to use some string formatting to make it look pretty, but this should get you started.

Comment: thank you i'll try it, and just to be clear, there doesn't need to be extra space, so i'm not sure if "output += '        | '" is necessary, i was just trying to make it look like a dataframe

Comment: If you need the data to work with it (instead of just printing it) you could use something like `[[1 if v in r else 0 for v in values] for r in rows]` instead to get a list of lists...